# How to concatenate several logical operators like 'a and not (b or c or d)'

Tags: python

How do I write this correctly:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SEARCHDIR):
    files = [f for f in files if not f[0] == '.' and not ("BLACKBOX" or ".RTN" or ".log") in f]
```

I want to achieve my file list to contain all files instead of hidden files or files conaining one of the strings "BLACKBOX" or ".RTN" or ".log".
Anyway only the first expression is evaluated ("BLACKBOX") the others are ignored.

Comment: i suggest a cleaner option, separating your construction of that list into several lines. much easier to read

Comment: You need to chain the *comparisons*, not the items you are comparing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both the `not` commands to one as

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SEARCHDIR):
    files = [f for f in files if not (f[0] == '.' and any(i in f for i in ["BLACKBOX", ".RTN", ".log"]))]
```

Comment: 'any' was the key

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
not ("BLACKBOX" or ".RTN" or ".log") in f
```

To this:

```
not any([x in f for x in ["BLACKBOX", ".RTN", ".log"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
filterFn = lambda f: f[0] == '.' or any(s in f for s in ['BLACKBOX','.RTN','.log'])
files = [f for f in files if not filterFn(f)]
```

My local test shows:

```
>>> files = [f for f in ('.', 'TEST', 'test.RTN') if not filterFn(f)]
>>> files
['TEST']
```